# Passing Multi-line PHP variable to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, character-encoding, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass a PHP variable holding a text value (html content) read from SQL database to a Javascript function. I'm trying all different approaches such as `json_encode(utf8_encode())` and `preg_replace()` but none of them seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ramtin_data;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM posts') as $row)
{
    $qtitle = $row['title'];
    $qcontent = $row['content'];
    $qpage = $row['page_id'];

    $qcontent = json_encode(utf8_encode($qcontent));

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        displayPost('$qtitle', '$qcontent');
    </script>";
}
?>
```

Just want to mention that when I insert a row in my database with a simple line (including `"`and `/`) in the `content` field, the above code works.

I've also tried the following code and got the same result:

```
$qcontent = preg_replace('/\v+|\\\[rn]/','<br/>', $qcontent);
```

The value inside the `content` field in the database is the following string:

```
<img src="images/death_truck_titleDisplay.jpg" width="400" height="140" class="globalImageStyle" /><p class="postBodyContentParagraph">The work for another Construct2 game "<a href="http://ramt.in">Death Truck</a>" has been started.</p><p class="postBodyContentParagraph">I've had the idea since a few weeks ago and I'm amazed that how much it had developed into better shapes and more complex gameplay ideas only through the first weeks that I've started working on the graphics and the game codes/logic.</p><p class="postBodyContentParagraph">I'm actually done with the truck and pedestrian graphics and movement codes (plus the interaction code between pedestrians and the truck) and have included the game in the projects page as a Work In Progress. You can check some of the graphics and the idea of the whole game (plus some gameplay ideas) in the projects page.</p>
```

How should I pass the above value to the `displayPost()` Javascript function?

**UPDATE**

---

The problem was with the single quotes inside the value. The accepted solution suggested all `'`s to be replaced with `\'` using `$qcontent = str_replace("'", "\'", $qcontent);` which worked perfectly.

The result however was quoted by `json_encode()` which I found the easiest way to remove the wrapping `"`s to be using `content.slice(1, content.length - 2)` (`content` is the second parameter which refers to `$qcontent` in the PHP section of the code) inside of the Javascript function.

Comment: quotes need to be escaped. really though, this should be an ajax request. you can send html inside json by setting the hexquote flag. just google how to encode html in json.

Comment: Quotes don't need to be escaped, if you are using two different ones.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: First of all, "not working" means that my Javascript function doesn't get called/invoked. Secondly, when I insert `"'test'"` in the database, the code's not working, but replaced the value in the database with `"test"` and everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wrap your output in single quotes `'` you need to escape those.

```
$qcontent = str_replace("'", "\'", $qcontent);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for. Just for clarification though, `json_encode()` doesn't escape single quotes `'`?

Comment: json_encode only converts the array or object to the JSON format. This format can hold strings, which escape quotes within the strings which are the same as the escapsulating quote. Otherwise you wouldn't know where the string ends. So you can see escaped strings within JSON, but always within two non-escaped quotes.

Comment: Actually, those two non-escaped quotes (wrapping double quotes) were successfully passed into the Javascript function and I had to use `split()` function in JS to get rid of them. But when I put single quotes inside the string it doesn't work anymore (before trying your code of course). Correct me if I'm wrong, it seems to me that json_encode() doesn't escape single quotes.

Comment: When the string is made of double quotes, only double quotes get escaped inside the string. That's what I meant with encapsulating :)